# Grey circle background on app icons

Tags: samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, app-icons

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 on Android 6.0 Marshmallow, and I just looked at the home screen and some of my app icons have a grey circle around them.

Is there any meanings of this? Is it possible to turn it off while still using TouchWiz?

[image: PayPal icon with grey circle background]

Comment: There's no meaning behind it, some launchers like perhaps your default Samsung launcher, try to add such backgrounds to the logos of apps, so that they all appear uniformly, like squares or circles. Try checking your launcher display settings if you can disable this or maybe try a different launcher that offers more control like Nova launcher.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after asking the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was fixed or not, but change the screen resolution and that should fix your icons.

Answer (score 0):

Some launchers have an option called "**Reshape legacy icons**". **Turn it off** to remove the background.